# Overwriting css root variables by adding a class to element

Tags: css, root, css-variables

I want to create a dark mode and I wonder if that'd be possible to achieve using this kind of logic. Maybe with some javascript or smth? Or is it just plain stupid :)? So in that scenario I ofc have some js toggle button that'd give a .night class to the body and with that would change a "light" do "dark"

```css
 :root{

    --light: #ffffff;

}


.night :root{

    --light: #000000;

}
```

Comment: :root equates to the html element basically, so if you add the class to body the selector would be the other way round.

Answer (score 6):

The `:root` selector is the `html` element in the document which encapsulates all of your web page

> The :root CSS pseudo-class matches the root element of a tree representing the document. In HTML, :root represents the  element and is identical to the selector html, except that its specificity is higher.
> [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)

Logically, the `:root` element is the highest element in the document as it holds all the elements in the page thus we cannot have `.some-selector :root` selector because the `html` element (`:root`) doesn't have a parent element.

So to fix the issue, you can add the class, you called it `.night`, to the `root` element itself. Here's a quick demo.

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  /** toggle the ".night" class on the HTML element by accessing "document.documentElement" property */
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('night');
});
```

```css
/** default "--light" variable's value is "#fff" */
:root {
  --light: #fff;
}

/** when the "html" element has the ".night" class we change the "--light" variable's value to "#000" */
:root.night {
  --light: #000;
}

/** just for the demo nothing important */
.demo {
  background-color: var(--light);
  /** follows the "--light" value in real time */
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">Toggle Night Mode</button>
<p class="demo">My background color will follow the selected theme (dark or light)</p>
```

> Learn more about [`CSS Custom Properties (variable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).